# VS 2010 can't create a integration services project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssis

I have installed sql server 2012 standard edition and SSDT (10.3.21208.0) is installed. 
But when I try to create an integration services project in VS 2010 professional edition I got the following message:

Microsoft Visual Studio is unable to load this document:

To design Integration Services packages in SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT), SSDT has to be installed by one of these editions of SQL Server 2012: Standard, Enterprise, Developer, or Evaluation. To install SSDT, run SQL Server Setup and select SQL Server Data Tools."

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue. I had first installed the express edition but later upgraded to standard to be able to use SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

Did you also have a SQL Server 2008 R2 installation before? It seems in some of the cases, the side-by-side installation tends to do some missteps. The suggest solution in the below article is to first uninstall the earlier Express/2008, then reinstall.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/99386641-daf9-4370-bf1e-a52affd8c1ef/vs2008-unable-to-load-integration-services-package-document-after-creation